# How to calculate total Fridays between two dates in excel on weekly, biweekly and monthly basis?

Tags: excel

My Start Date is 1/1/2016 and End Date is 12/31/2016.
I want to calculate total biweekly Fridays between range.

BI-WEEKLY: 
If I give Quarterly range Start Date is 1/1/2016 and End Date is 3/31/2016, my formula working fine **=CEILING(INT((WEEKDAY(A1-6)-A1+A2)/7)/2,1)** but failed for Semi annual and Annual case

WEEKLY:
Formula for weekly **INT((WEEKDAY(A1-6)-A1+A2)/7** working fine in all cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "bi-weekly"?  For example from 1st to 30th April 2016 there are 5 Fridays.  What number are you expecting for bi-weekly?

Comment: Yes i want to calculate 3 Fridays only, and with using my formula it calculate 3 Fridays perfectly but when the same 5 Fridays fall in any other month then this formula failed. biweekly means after every one week

Comment: Sorry, still not clear - what do you mean by "after every one week"?  Will every 5 Friday month be 3 bi-weekly Fridays?

Comment: yes right every 5 Friday month will be 3 bi-weekly Fridays

Comment: So, if we are calculating bi-weekly Fridays starting from 1st April 2016, they will be: 01.04, 15.04, 29.04... and the next one is 06.05 or 13.05? Are bi-weekly Fridays calculates starting from first day of every month?

Comment: Your going to have to use IF to cater for weekdays above, below and equal to 6 to make this work

Comment: @Tosique no, it will be like starting from 1st April 2016, then 01.04, 15.04, 29.04... and the next one is 13.05 or 27.05 , but problem is solved thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Formulas to calculate total number of Fridays between two dates in excel on weekly, biweekly and monthly basis.
**A1** = Start date of the period , **A2**= End date of the period,
If in Excel , week is start with Sunday then the value for **Friday** will be **6**

```
Formula for Weekly = INT((WEEKDAY(A1-6)-A1+A2)/7  
Formula for Bi - Weekly = CEILING(INT((WEEKDAY(A1-6)-A1+A2)/7)/2,1  
Formula for Monthly = (YEAR(A2)-YEAR(A1))*12+MONTH(A2)-MONTH(A1)+1
```

Hopefully, it would be worked for all as it worked for me :)